# Direction of Area Vector of a simple 2D figure

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, coordinate-systems, vectors, conventions

For a two-dimensional plate placed in the $xy$-plane, while calculating the electric flux, should we consider direction of the area vector along $\hat{k}$ or $-\hat{k}$?

Comment: Whichever is outward from the inside of surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a open surface, it is usually in that direction which make acute angle with electric field.